# How reshape pandas dataframe side by side based on a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am just trying to do the following exercise: I want to use the values of column A as an aggregator for Column B, but instead of using a function like "sum" or "mean", I want to have the values side by side. let me give you an example.

Before:

```
d = {'A': [0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4],
     'B': [10,11,17,13,15,2,3,19,20,21]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df

A   B
0   10
1   11
2   17
3   13
4   15
0   2
1   3
2   19
3   20
4   21
```

How I would like to see it:

```
A   D   E
0   10  2
1   11  3
2   17  19
3   13  20
4   15  21
```

In my head, the solution would be using `unstack` or maybe a `groupby`, but I can't think of how to formulate it.

Thanks

Comment: Q/A 10 on the dup link.

Comment: `new_df = df.set_index(['A', df.groupby('A').cumcount()]).unstack()`

Comment: `new_df = df.set_index(['A', df.groupby('A').cumcount()]).unstack().set_axis(['D', 'E'], axis=1).reset_index()` for exact output